# Spring boot - custom login controller

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Angular 2 with Spring boot. The login page is coming from the Angular 2 server and I am trying to use the Spring login controller to authenticate. It seems there is no login controller and only the servler - j_spring_security_check. How do I write my custom login controller without using the Spring Login page. 
  Also , my application is using the LDAP from Spring boot.

My controller is as below

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping("/api/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="name") String name,@RequestParam(value="password") String password) {
        System.out.println("My login controller");
        System.out.println("User name is " + name);
        System.out.println("Passwird is " + password);
        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);

        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        System.out.println(result.getPrincipal());
        System.out.println(result.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
        return "ok";
    }

}



My web security config is as below 

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                             
            //.antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
            /*.and()
            .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/api");*///.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/404");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns(new String[]{"uid={0},ou=people"})
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                    //.passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), "dc=springframework,dc=org");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` ?

Comment: Why would you need your own controller? Just use http basic or the form login and post to that URL using Angular.

Comment: When I give /login it is sending the default login.jsp as a response. I thought I will get logged in. Should I call the servlet instead?

Comment: @Chaoluo - How will I direct Angular2 to hit the Filter? or how will I direct the filter to use the LDAP configured?

Comment: if you're writing a custom filter.... maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/39281738/206466 you can also customize the response of the default form login.

Comment: You should `POST` to the `/login` URL not `GET`

Comment: Finally, I got an implementation that gave me an end to end view - I followed it http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/. Thanks everyone.